# Suppose $T=[u_1,...,u_n][v_1,...,v_n]^*$ Why does $Tv_j=u_j$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n$ and $s_j$ be singular value of $A$ with associated left singular vectors $u_1,u_2,....u_n$ and associated right singular vectors $v_1,v_2,....v_n$

Suppose $T=[u_1,...,u_n][v_1,...,v_n]^*$

Why does $Tv_j=u_j$?

(for all $j$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** $T = UV^*$, and $v_j = Ve_j$ where $e_j$ denotes the $j$th standard basis vector

Comment: $V^*v_j = V^*(Ve_j) = (V^*V)e_j$